# Change tile size for ggplot2 heatmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap

I'm making a heatmap in R using ggplot2 and I want to change the size of my tiles because the text in my heatmap doesn't fit in the cells. Below is my data and attempted plots.

```
library("ggplot2")
s = sprintf("dataset number %s", 1:9)
vars = sprintf("many many words here, here and here %s", 1:6)
data = data.frame(s = rep(s, 6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$variable = rep(vars, rep.int(9, 6))
data$variable = as.factor(data$variable)
data$value = rep.int(-1000, 54)
data$font = "plain"
for(v in (unique(data$s))) {
  ids = which(data$s %in% "dataset number 1")
  vals = data[ids, ]
  row = rownames(vals[vals$value %in% max(vals$value, na.rm = TRUE), ])
  data[row, ]$font = "bold"
}
```

I'm making a heatmap like this

```
title = "Heatmap"
cbbPalette = list(grey = "#999999", black = "#000000", orange = "#E69F00", sky = "#56B4E9", green = "#009E73", yellow = "#F0E442", blue = "#0072B2", darko = "#D55E00", 
                  pink = "#CC79A7")

pdf(sprintf("./heatmap.pdf"))
heatmap = ggplot(data = data, aes(x = variable, y = s, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = cbbPalette$pink, high = cbbPalette$green, mid = cbbPalette$grey, 
                       midpoint = 0, limit = c(-100,100), space = "Lab", 
                       name=title) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(data$variable)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6 - 0.5, color = "white", size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2 + 0.5, color = "white", size = 1) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 16, hjust = 1), legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16)) +
  coord_fixed()

#add numbers to cells
heatmap = heatmap + geom_text(aes(x = variable, y = s, label = value, fontface = font), color = cbbPalette$black, size = 3) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.justification = c(0.5, 0),
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "top") + 
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 7, barheight = 1,
                               title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))
# Print the heatmap
print(heatmap)
dev.off()
```

And I get the following result -- [heatmap](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ylo6s1rad710pw2/heatmap.pdf?dl=0)

Other SO posts suggested to change width and height within `geom_tile`, but I get the following result:

```
heatmap = ggplot(data = data, aes(x = variable, y = s, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", aes(width = 2L)) + ...
```

[wrong_heatmap](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxhc9mfezfvaaw5/wrong_heatmap.pdf?dl=0)

I also tried changing height in `geom_tile` as well as `coord_fixed(ratio = 1L)` but without any success.

Also, I know that I can simply change the size of the text and numbers will fit, but I need to keep the font size the same. I can also shorten the labels but assume this is not an option.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Hi damir. The problem seems to be that your plot is too small because it is surrounded by large text elements. If you don't want to change your font size or make the x axis labels shorter, then the only way to make the boxes bigger is to increase the page size of the pdf. Otherwise this a bit like asking "how can I double the size of my feet without changing my shoe size?" - it's not physically possible to fit all the things you want to fit on the pdf. That's why ggplot has shrunk the plot down - to accommodate the text at the size you wanted on the page size you asked for.

Comment: @AllanCameron, that makes sense. Thanks!